# Possible typographical error in Michael Searcoid's book?

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-explanation

Let $\overline{S}$ denote closure of $S$ and $S^\circ$ denote the interior of $S$. The theorem did not state that we are dealing with subsets $U$ in $S$, but the proof makes this assumption. If it's not a typo then I would like to know why we can make this assumption.
[image]

Comment: The proof doesn't assume that $U$ is in $S$; it says that *if* $U$ is in $S$, then ...

Comment: Okay. But how does that help show that $S^\circ$ is the largest subset of $X$. Seeing that the conclusion was $U^\circ \subseteq S^\circ$ then I am assuming that the strategy is to show that all the other subsets are in $S^\circ$..? thanks

Comment: That same sentence is effectively saying that it must be the largest open subset because it contains all other open subsets. Don't read the conclusion as $U^\circ \subseteq S^\circ$ but as $U \subseteq S^\circ$.

Comment: How could we show that there ***not** any subsets $U$ in $X\setminus S$ that are bigger than $S$?

Comment: @TheLastCipher In what sense could a subset of $X\setminus S$ be bigger than $S$? Also, $S^\circ$ is the largest *subset of $S$* that is open in $X.$ Subsets of $X\setminus S$ are not subsets of $S$ (other than the empty set)

Comment: @TheLastCipher By "the biggest" set with property P they mean that every set with property P is a subset of it. In other words, the greatest element amongst the sets with property P under the partial order $\subseteq.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: I'm sorry. what I meant was subsets $U$ in $X$ that are not necessarily contained in $S$. For instance, what if $S$ is empty?

Comment: which would entail $\partial S\cup S$ is empty

Comment: They don't have property P so you don't need to worry about them. (Property P is being an open subset of $S.$)

Comment: If $S$ is empty then the largest (and only) open subset of $S$ is the empty set. So the interior of the empty set is the empty set.

Comment: so for the delayed response because I had to do something else. Anyway, I understand now and I feel embarassed lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Théophile comments, it's an assumption for the sake of argument, not an assumption.

What you want to prove is that $S^\circ$ is the largest open subset of $S.$ This means that any open subset of $S$ is contained in $S^\circ.$ You start a proof of this by saying "let $U$ be an (arbitrary) open subset of $S$..." and then show that $U\subseteq S^\circ.$

Comment: Yeah. But the way I understand the proposition is "any open subset of $X$ is in $S^\circ$". So the way I understand is that we are not only dealing with subsets of $S$ but all subsets $U$ in $X$. Is it not?

Comment: @TheLastCipher  Huh? what proposition do you understand like that? The only set that has the property that any open subset of $X$ is a subset of it is $X$ itself.

Comment: The "if" at the beginning of the sentence also applies to $U \subseteq S$. **If** $U$ is an open subset of $X$ and **if** $U \subseteq S$, then ...